# Grails 3.0.1 - how and where to configure grails.gorm.default.mapping

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-3.0

I had in the old Config.groovy:

```
grails.gorm.default.mapping = {
    id generator = 'identity'

    // send only the dirty fields to the database for updating
    dynamicUpdate = true
    dynamicInsert = true
}
```

So I put this in the additionally application.groovy, but it won't be respected any more. All updates are full, sending all fields to the database, even the not changed ones.

I tried to translate this in application.yml:

```
grails:
    gorm:
        default:
            mapping:
                id generator:  "identity"
                dynamicUpdate: true
                dynamicInsert: true
```

... but still without luck.

Comment: I discovered in the sources a Settings.groovy which still contains grails.gorm.default.constraints but **not** a grails.gorm.default.mapping any more, so it seems this won't be evaluated any more globally. There may still be a KungFu with the application.yml, spring or hibernate, but I didn't found it yet.

Comment: Try adding a `application.groovy` and specifying it there

Comment: You're right: it was no need for KungFu, it was just simple as this. Thank you Graeme, it works :)

Comment: @GraemeRocher Hi, when I am specifying whole **Config.groovy** file in **application.groovy** it is showing me an error of `Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':profile'. Type 'gradle dependencies' for more information`. On running `gradle dependency`, none of them failed. But when I am specifying in **application.yml**, it works fine! Is there any way to specify only in **application.groovy** or any config to default load **application.groovy**?

Comment: Is there a way to set default constraints when using Spring Boot only, not in Grails?

Comment: @IgorDonin have you been able to figure this out? I am also looking for global constraint in spring boot application with groovy.

Comment: @Vivek Unfortunately, I gave up trying to use GORM with Spring Boot. It was just too expensive trying to solve all the issues I found. Better luck for you.

Answer (score 2):

With Grails 3.1.10, it works in application.groovy:

```
dataSource {
  //....
}

grails.gorm.default.mapping = {
    uuid index:'idx_uuid', type: org.hibernate.type.UUIDCharType, length: 36, defaultValue: null
    batchSize 15000
}
```

but had no sucess either while putting it in application.yml

Comment: When using the closure based config in application.groovy, Jackson serializer fails in the /env activator endpoint.

Comment: I didn't notice any problem but I do not use this activator, as far as I know. It seems to be already reported :

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7242