# Grails 3.0.1 - how to configure grails.gorm.default.constraints in application.yml

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-3.0

I took the old configuration:

```
grails.gorm.default.constraints = {
    '*' (nullable: true, blank: true)
}
```

... and put it in the `application.groovy`.

Luckily it worked as expected.

How would one define this in `application.yml`? I tried:

```
grails:
    gorm:
        default:
            constraints:
                '*' (nullable: true, blank: true)
```

but this gives errors on start.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`application.groovy` is the place to do that. Groovy code in a `.yml` config file is invalid and not supported.

Comment: It's an important information. Thanks! I had the false feeling, that all former configuration could be rewritten with YAML syntax. But as I described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29516108/grails-3-0-1-how-and-where-to-configure-grails-gorm-default-mapping not all the old configuration will still be accepted in application.groovy

Comment: Is anyone planning on updating the documentation? It still says to use the various .groovy config files from Grails 2, and, even though the documentation mentions application.groovy in section 4.1, which I read more than once, it still took me until I read this to figure out to put the old configuration in application.groovy instead. This is especially obnoxious considering the yaml is the default.

Comment: " It still says to use the various .groovy config files from Grails 2" - Are there specific sections that you can point out that need attention? Help would be appreciated.  I know there are gaps in the docs that we still need to close. If you are of the mind to contribute to the solution to that problem, pull requests to https://github.com/grails/grails-doc are also welcomed.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown, `application.groovy` does not exist in a new Grails 3.0 project.  Is the idea to just create the file next to its `.yml` sibling in the `grails-app/conf` folder?

Comment: Grails 3 doesn't have an `application.groovy`. It was replaces with `application.yml` and the documentatiion didn't catch up yet. This answer is not valid since the user asked for a solution on the `yml` format.

Comment: @DemPilafian That is right.  The framework does not create the file by default because `yml` is preferred.  If you want `application.groovy` create it in `grails-app/conf/`.

Comment: @sargas We didn't replace `application.groovy` with `application.yml` in Grails 3.  There was never an `application.groovy` in previous versions.  We introduced support for that in Grails 3 for folks who want to use `.groovy` instead of or in addition to `application.yml`.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I stand corrected. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: if you dont like to put it in application.groovy you could create a file called runtime.groovy and place it there as described here http://docs.grails.org/4.0.10/guide/single.html#config